# pip: install package at version that don't bump versions of other packages

Tags: python, pip

I know that project uses `django == 1.3`. Stacktrace shown that I miss package `django-photologue`. Command

```
pip install django-photologue
```

download `django == 1.7`. How to dump requirement for all possible version of selected package or ever better - dump only that have additional constraint for it dependencies?

I get project that have no `requirements.txt` file so try recreate working environment.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I end with:

```
pip install -v --no-deps --no-install django-photologue
```

which dump version as list:

```
Downloading/unpacking django-photologue
  Using version 3.1.1 (newest of versions: 3.1.1, 3.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0, 2.8.3, 2.8.2, 2.8.1, 2.8, 2.7, 2.6.1, 2.6, 2.5, 2.4, 2.3)
```

I can manually install each versions and check dependencies.

Another way investigate URLs in:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-photologue/json
```